# make use of Elastic search dsl python analyze api

Tags: python, regex, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-dsl-py

How to make use of default _analyze in elastic search dsl python?

My query looks like below:

```
query = Q('regexp', field_name = "f04((?!z).)*")
search_obj = Search(using = conn, index = index_name, doc_type = type_name).query(query)
response = search_obj[0:count].execute()
```

Where do i put `analyze() method` so that i get to see how my `"f04((?!z).)*"` is getting broken into terms? Actually it seems like `'!'` doesn't work as regex. How do i change the anaylzer if default analyzer is unable to take `'!'` as regexp character?

I'm very new to use, finding little hard to accurately put analyze method in my code. PLease help.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what exactly you want to achieve. If you posted a CURL query that does what you want, it would make it easier to translate it into Elasticsearch DSl or elasticsearch-py interface.

If you're looking for an alternative to `_analyze` method but in Python, you can achieve it using elasticsearch-py, I'm not sure you can do that using Elasticsearch DSL though. So let's say I want to see the results of how my string `jestem biały miś` is analyzed using my analyzer named `morfologik`. Using CURL I would just run:

```
$ curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/morf_texts/_analyze" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "analyzer": "morfologik",
  "text": "jestem biały miś"
}'

{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "być",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 6,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "biały",
      "start_offset": 7,
      "end_offset": 12,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "miś",
      "start_offset": 13,
      "end_offset": 16,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "misić",
      "start_offset": 13,
      "end_offset": 16,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

In order to achieve the same result using elasticsearch-py, you can run the following:

```py
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch.client import IndicesClient

client = Elasticsearch()
indices_client = IndicesClient(client)

indices_client.analyze(
    body={
        "analyzer": "morfologik",
        "text": "jestem biały miś",
    }
)
```

The output of the `analyze` method is the same as of the above CURL request:

```py
{'tokens': [{'token': 'być',
   'start_offset': 0,
   'end_offset': 6,
   'type': '<ALPHANUM>',
   'position': 0},
  {'token': 'biały',
   'start_offset': 7,
   'end_offset': 12,
   'type': '<ALPHANUM>',
   'position': 1},
  {'token': 'miś',
   'start_offset': 13,
   'end_offset': 16,
   'type': '<ALPHANUM>',
   'position': 2},
  {'token': 'misić',
   'start_offset': 13,
   'end_offset': 16,
   'type': '<ALPHANUM>',
   'position': 2}]}
```